# Variable in Android which stays even after app destroys

Tags: android, variables, syntax, scope, lifetime

I need a variable which didn't get destroy after the app get closed.
E.g. I want to determine that, did user start the app before or this is the first time.
If user did then variable define 1 and if the user starting the app for the first time for then variable define 0.

So is there any way to stay the variable and it's value even after app get closed?

Comment: you have to shared preferences for saving this variable and retrieve every time the user opens the app

Comment: what? I didn't understand. What do you mean by shared preference?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

save variable like this

```
sharedpreferences.edit().putBoolean("is_first_time",false).apply()
```

and retrieve the same variable on next time

```
Boolena isFirstTime = sharedpreferences.getBoolean("is_first_time",true).apply()
```

Comment: I don't know the method but on 3rd line of code why are you assigning value to true with use of getBoolean method? As getters just return value

Comment: that is the default value, if the is_first_time does not exist in shared preferences, then it returns true as the default value

Comment: instead of true or false I want to assign integer value to Preference.

Comment: yes you can, instead of putBoolean, use putInt,putString or similar methods in shared preferences

Comment: Thx!!! I'm always thankful to stackoverflow and helpers like you who solves my problem this fast